# Qual a diferença entre um projeto VBA e uma macro VBA?

Tags: vba

estava estudando macros VBA e me veio a seguinte duvida: **Qual a diferença entre um projeto VBA e uma macro VBA?**

Os dois são a mesma coisa ou tem alguma diferença significativa entre eles?

Comment: O que pode causar confusão entre os termos é que há quem considere macro apenas aquelas gravadas pelo editor de macro, mas na verdade aquelas que você programa (o que seria o "projeto vba") também são macros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu diria que não são a mesma coisa:

[image: VBA Project]

Um projecto é um conjunto de "objectos" que podem conter Macros.

Comment: então seria correto afirmar que uma macro VBA é uma rotina de programação, enquanto um projeto VBA é a junção de diversas macros e outros objetos, como arquivos e imagens  por exemplo?

Comment: Sim, macros são rotinas de programação. O projecto pode conter objectos como módulos que contêm macros ou forms que são interfaces com o utilizador que também incluem código (VBA). Na imagem em cima vê a estrutura de um projecto VBA de um ficheiro excel. Todos os objectos podem conter macros (código).

Answer (score 2):

São a mesma coisa, o VBA - Visual Basic For Application, é uma linguagem de programação utilizada pela microsoft que roda por tras de suas aplicação office e outros, então para voce ter um projeto VBA voce irá criar algumas macros, no caso sub rotinas